# Java : return custom object from constructor

Tags: java, polymorphism

I want to return object in constructor where I can assign values to new object

Code

Abstract Class:

```java
public abstract class Models implements Serializable {
    
   public Models(Object id) throws Exception {
      this.find(id);
   }
   
   public <T extends  Models>  T find(Object id) throws Exception {
      Map<String, T>  data = new HashMap<>();
      Long idSerialized = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(id));
      hibernateContext(
         session -> data.put(
            "obj",
            (T) session.get(this.getClass(), idSerialized)
         )
      );
      return data.get("obj");
   }

}
```

child class:

```java
public class Users  extends Models implements Serializable {
   public Users(Object id) throws Exception {
      super(id);
      this.encrypted_field = "password";
   }
}
```

Comment: Nope... If you want to control object creation, you can't count on constructors. Use static factory methods.

Comment: Nice idea because i have methods , i don't an object to be initialized ! Thanks

Comment: Its a good idea but i cannot make this (keyword refer to this object) a static field !